# PHP class to represent types of refrigerants

Tags: php, beginner, csv

I'm relatively experienced with Java and C++ so picking up PHP wasn't too difficult. I wanted to get some feedback on my first PHP class. There's nothing extremely complicated as of now, but its nice to get feedback.

The only part I feel that I will definitely get feedback is for the readCSV() function. I made it specifically this way as I need to read the csv file row by row for each column rather than column by column. I couldn't figure out how to do that with `foreach` so I had to revert to the regular `for` loop.

```
<?php

/**
 * Description of Refrigerant
 * Class for the refrigerant. Stores information about the refrigerant as well
 * as functions to calculate values including but not limited to
 * SEI, COP, Enthalpy, Pressure temp
 * @author Eric
 */
class Refrigerant {
    /*
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     *                       Variable Declaration
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     */

    // public variables to be accessed straight from the object
    public $refrigerantType;    // Type of refrigerant -> a string value
    // "r22" "r404a" etc
    // protected variables only to be accessed within the class and sub classes
    // Arrays of charts, temperature[key] will link to the pressure[key]
    protected $temperature;     // temperature chart
    protected $pressure;        // pressure chart
    protected $liquidEnthalpy;  // liquid enthalpy chart
    protected $vaporEnthalpy;   // vapor enthalpy chart
    protected $ratio;           // ratio of the liquid, suction and discharge factors

    /*
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     *                       Constructor & Destructor
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     */

    /**
     * Constructor for the refrigerant class
     * Only requires a type of refrigerant to be declared
     * @param string $rtype     ex. "r22", "r404a"
     */
    function __construct($rtype) {
        $this->refrigerantType = $rtype;
        $this->temperature = [];
        $this->pressure = [];
        $this->liquidEnthalpy = [];
        $this->vaporEnthalpy = [];
        $this->ratio = [];
    }

    /*
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     *                       Reading CSV Functions
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     */

    /**
     * Attempts to read a .csv file with the specific delimeter character
     * @param string $file      filename to open
     * @param char $delimiter   delimter to use
     */
    function readCSV($file, $delimiter) {

        // Read the file into a 2D array and store it in data
        $data = $this->get2DArrayFromCsv($file, $delimiter);

        // Read the data column by column and save the information based on the 
        // header of the column
        // Find how many columns we are reading
        $cols = count($data[0]);
        for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) {

            // For each column
            $rows = count($data);
            for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {

                // This will not execute anything if the cell is empty
                if ($data[$row][$col] == "") {
                    break;
                }
                // Dont parse any of the header data
                if ($row > 0) {
                    switch ($data[0][$col]) {
                        case 'Temperature':
                            array_push($this->temperature, $data[$row][$col]);
                            break;
                        case 'Pressure':
                            array_push($this->pressure, $data[$row][$col]);
                            break;
                        case 'Liquid Ent':
                            array_push($this->liquidEnthalpy, $data[$row][$col]);
                            break;
                        case 'Vapor Ent':
                            array_push($this->vaporEnthalpy, $data[$row][$col]);
                            break;
                        case 'Liquid':
                            $this->ratio = $this->array_push_assoc($this->ratio, 'Liquid', (float) $data[$row][$col]);
                            break;
                        case 'Discharge':
                            $this->ratio = $this->array_push_assoc($this->ratio, 'Discharge', (float) $data[$row][$col]);
                            break;
                        case 'Suction':
                            $this->ratio = $this->array_push_assoc($this->ratio, 'Suction', (float) $data[$row][$col]);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            /* Only if some rows will have less columns than the previous
              if ($col + 1 < count($data)) {
              $cols = count($data[$col + 1]);
              } */
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads the csv file and returns the data in a 2d array to be parsed
     * @param string $file          file name
     * @param string $delimiter     delimeter
     * @return array                2d array of the data
     */
    private function get2DArrayFromCsv($file, $delimiter) {
        if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            $i = 0;
            while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($lineArray); $j++) {
                    $data2DArray[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j];
                }
                $i++;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        return $data2DArray;
    }

    /*
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     *                       Calculating Values Functions
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     */

    /**
     * Finds the pressure temperature based on the pressure passed to the 
     * function. Accesses the temperature and pressure charts to find the new
     * temperature value using interpolation
     * @param double $newPressure   pressure value 
     * @return double               temperature corresponding to the new pressure
     */
    function pressureTemp($newPressure) {


        $values = $this->findBoundValues($this->pressure, $this->temperature, $newPressure);
        // interpolate the values
        $lowPressure = $values[0];
        $highPressure = $values[1];
        $lowTemp = $values[2];
        $highTemp = $values[3];

        if ($values[4] == "int") {
            $temp = $this->interpolate($lowPressure, $highPressure, $lowTemp, $highTemp, $newPressure);
        } else if ($values[4] == "ext") {
            $temp = $this->extrapolate($lowPressure, $highPressure, $lowTemp, $highTemp, $newPressure);
        }


        // We want to find temp, so first two values are pressure
        // second two are temperatures, and last is the new presssure
        /*
          print "{$lowPressure} -- {$lowTemp}<br>";
          print "{$newPressure} -- {$temp}<br>";
          print "{$highPressure} -- {$highTemp}<br>";
         * 
         */
        return $temp;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the subcooling value by subtracting the dlt from sat
     * Used by the liquid state
     * @param double $sat       Saturating condensing temperature
     * @param double $dlt       Drop leg temperature
     * @return double           subcooling value
     */
    function subcooling($sat, $dlt) {
        return $sat - $dlt;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the superheat value by subtracting the state pressure temp from
     * the state temperature
     * Discharge temperature - Discharge pressure temperature
     * Suction temperature - Suction pressure temperature
     * @param double $stateTemp             discharge/suction temperature
     * @param double $statePressureTemp     discharge/suction pressure temperature
     * @return double                       superheat value
     */
    function superheat($stateTemp, $statePressureTemp) {
        return $stateTemp - $statePressureTemp;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the enthalpy value of the given state, using temp1 and temp2 values
     * @param string $state     Liquid, Discharge, Suction 
     * @param double $temp1     Pressure used to find the pressure temp 
     * @param double $temp2     for liquid drop leg temp
     * @return double           enthalpy value for the specific state
     */
    function enthalpy($state, $temp1, $temp2) {
        switch ($state) {
            case 'Liquid':
                // Liquid - Subcooling
                $sct = $this->pressureTemp($temp1);
                $values = $this->findBoundValues($this->temperature, $this->liquidEnthalpy, $sct);
                $intVal = $this->interpolate($values[0], $values[1], $values[2], $values[3], $values[4]);
                return $intVal - ($this->subcooling($sct, $temp2) * $this->ratio['Liquid']);
            //break;
            case 'Discharge':
                // Discharge - Superheat
                $dsct = $this->pressureTemp($temp1);
                $values = $this->findBoundValues($this->temperature, $this->vaporEnthalpy, $dsct);
                $intVal = $this->interpolate($values[0], $values[1], $values[2], $values[3], $values[4]);
                return $intVal + ($this->superheat($dsct, $temp2) * $this->ratio['Discharge']);

            case 'Suction':
                // Suction - Superheat
                $sst = $this->pressureTemp($temp1);
                $values = $this->findBoundValues($this->temperature, $this->vaporEnthalpy, $sst);
                $intVal = $this->interpolate($values[0], $values[1], $values[2], $values[3], $values[4]);
                return $intVal + ($this->superheat($sst, $temp2) * $this->ratio['Discharge']);

            default:
                echo "enthalpy default case";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds the three enthalpy values, then uses them to calculate the COP
     * 
     * @param double $temp1     pressure used to find the pressure temp 
     * @param double $temp2     
     * @return double           COP value
     */
    function COP($temp1, $temp2) {
        $liquid = $this->enthalpy('Liquid', $temp1, $temp2);
        $suction = $this->enthalpy('Suction', $temp1, $temp2);
        $discharge = $this->enthalpy('Discharge', $temp1, $temp2);

        return ($suction - $liquid) / ($discharge - $liquid);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $outdoorTemp     outdoor air temp in celsius
     * @param double $temp1         pressure used to find the pressure temp 
     * @param double $temp2
     * @return double               SEI value      
     */
    function SEI($outdoorTemp, $temp1, $temp2) {

        // Convert outdoor air temp to kelvin
        $a = $outdoorTemp + 273;

        $d = $this->enthalpy('Suction', $temp1, $temp2) + 273;

        $t = $d / ($a - $d);

        $cop = $this->COP($temp1, $temp2);

        return $cop / $t * 100;

    }

    /*
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     *                       Functions used by Calculations
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     */

    /**
     * Finds the lower and upper bounds of the two variables being used for
     * interpolation or extrapolation calculations. It also returns if it 
     * is a interpolation or extrapolation calculation
     * @param array $xArray     array of values which x actual will be in
     * @param array $yArray     array of values which will contain the coressponding value to xActual
     * @param double $xActual   the actual value we are using to find the coressponding value
     * @return array            values stored 0 through 4
     *              0 - double - lower bound of xArray
     *              1 - double - higher bound of xArray
     *              2 - double - lower bound of yArray
     *              3 - double - higher bound of yArray
     *              4 - string - ext or int for extrapolation or interpolation
     */
    function findBoundValues($xArray, $yArray, $xActual) {

        $values = [];
        // Check to see if the new pressure is below the lowest known point    
        // or if it is above the highest known point
        $numPoints = count($xArray);
        // If the new pressure is lower than the lowest point we have
        if ($xActual <= $xArray[0]) {

            // Set the lowest and highest pressure/temperatures to the first
            // and second lowest and extrapolate from there
            $values[0] = $xArray[0];
            $values[1] = $xArray[1];

            $values[2] = $yArray[0];
            $values[3] = $yArray[1];
            $values[4] = "ext";
            return $values;
        } else if ($xActual >= $xArray[$numPoints - 1]) {
            // If the new pressure is higher than the highest point we have
            // Set the lowest and highest pressure/temperatures to the first
            // and second lowest and extrapolate from there
            $values[0] = $xArray[$numPoints - 2];
            $values[1] = $xArray[$numPoints - 1];

            $values[2] = $yArray[$numPoints - 2];
            $values[3] = $yArray[$numPoints - 1];
            $values[4] = "ext";

            return $values;
        } else {
            // New pressure point is somewhere in the range of values on the chart
            foreach ($xArray as $key => $value) {
                // The current value is higher than the new pressure, so set
                // the higher bound values, lower bound will already be set
                if ($value > $xActual) {
                    $values[1] = $value;
                    $values[3] = $yArray[$key];
                    break;
                } else {
                    // Every time we pass a point that is lower than the new pressure
                    // we set the lower bound values
                    $values[0] = $value;
                    $values[2] = $yArray[$key];
                }
            }
            $values[4] = "int";
            return $values;
        }
    }

    /**
     * interpolate function
     * @param double $x1        low end of left side
     * @param double $x2        high end of left side
     * @param double $y1        low end of right side
     * @param double $y2        high end of right side
     * @param double $xActual   value inbetween x1 and x2
     * @return double           the value matching the xActual value on 
     *                          the scale of the Y values
     */
    function interpolate($x1, $x2, $y1, $y2, $xActual) {

        $xDiff = abs($x1 - $x2);
        $yDiff = abs($y1 - $y2);


        $xPer = abs($x1 - $xActual) / abs($xDiff);
        $newY = $y1 + ($xPer * $yDiff);

        return $newY;
    }

    /**
     * extrapolate function - the new point is not
     * @param double $x1        low end of left side
     * @param double $x2        high end of left side
     * @param double $y1        low end of right side
     * @param double $y2        high end of right side
     * @param double $xActual   value inbetween x1 and x2
     * @return double           the value matching the xActual value on
     *                          the scale of the Y values
     */
    function extrapolate($x1, $x2, $y1, $y2, $xActual) {

        $xDiff = abs($x1 - $x2);
        $yDiff = abs($y1 - $y2);

        $xPer = abs($x1 - $xActual) / abs($xDiff);

        // If the actual value is below, we subtract it from the lower value
        // If the acutal value is higher, we add it to the higher value
        if ($xActual <= $x1) {
            $newY = $y1 - ($xPer * $yDiff);
        } else if ($xActual >= $x2) {
            $newY = $y2 + ($xPer * $yDiff);
        }
        return $newY;
    }

    /*
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     *                       Quality of Life (QoL) Functions
     * ===================================================================
     * ===================================================================
     */

    /**
     * Adds a value to an associative array 
     * @param array $array      array to add a value to
     * @param string $key       key of the array to add to
     * @param double $value     value to be added
     * @return array            the array being modified
     */
    function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value) {
        $array[$key] = $value;
        return $array;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `function enthalpy` surely looks strange. Three cases are not at all connected, and I don't see a reason to combine them into single function like this.

  Also, I fail to see the difference between `Discharge` and `Suction` cases. Shouldn't it be `ratio['Suction']` in the latter case?

  If I am correct, the recommendation is to negate values of `ratio['Liquid']`, and rewrite it as

  ```
  function enthalpy($state, $temp1, $temp2) {
      $sct = $this->pressureTemp($temp1);
      $values = $this->findBoundValues($this->temperature, $this->liquidEnthalpy, $sct);
      $intVal = $this->interpolate($values[0], $values[1], $values[2], $values[3], $values[4]);
      return $intVal + ($this->subcooling($sct, $temp2) * $this->ratio[state]);
  }
  ```
- Since you `// Dont parse any of the header data`, it is much cleaner to start the row loop from 1, and do not check `if (row > 0)` at all.
- I don't follow why do you want to read the file like that. PHP allows accessing members by name, like `$this->$name[$col]`, where `$name` array is constructed from the values of `row[0]`.